# Run a script as root being a normal user with sudo package removed

Tags: linux, debian, root

I want my users can run a script, but this script has to be executed as root. The "problem" is sudo package is not installed and I do not wanna install it. Is there a way to perform this?

More details:

suppose my script is located in /usr/sbin/my_script/my_script.sh

so I want my users run a command like that:

my_script [options]

but as I said before the script/service belongs root and need to run as root.

Any solution?

Comment: Your script will not work unless you install Sudo. That is the way it works.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/364/108618

Comment: Perhaps polkit is your friend ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible with something called setuid bit. Usually a program/script is run with the rights of the launcher. Setuid changes this and the program is run with the right of the owner of the file.

In the past you could set setuid on the script, but that is no longer allowed for security reasons. A workaround is to use a compiled [wrapper](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts) which gets the setuid. Create file wrapper.c with bellow contents.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    setuid( 0 );   // you can set it at run time also
    system( "/home/your_user/your_script.bash" );
    return 0;
 }
```

Next compile the script and assign appropriate permissions. Also make sure that the script is not owned or writable by the user, or else can do whatever they want.

```
  (install gcc with your systems package manager)
# gcc wrapper.c -o wrapper
# chown root:root wrapper
# chmod u+s wrapper

$ ./wrapper (now runs with root permissions)
```

With that being said, using sudo is likely a lot easier and safer. Sudo is basically a setuid wrapper, but a lot smarter and more flexible. If you do end up using sudo, do something like below:

```
(add to /etc/sudoers)
your_user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/your_user/your_script.bash

$ sudo ./your_script.bash
```

This is easy to setup, safer and your user does not need to be part of the sudo/wheel/admin group. They are only allowed to execute that one script. Still need to be sure that they can't change the script.